# How to pre-populate field from ForeignKey on Django via decorator?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have 3 classes on my model in Django 1.11 & Python3.5:

Class 1:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Class 2:

```
class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Class 3:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="city_set", max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    birthplace = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="birthplace_set", max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def country(self):
        if not self.city:
            return False
        else:
            negara = City.objects.get(name=self)
            return negara.country

    @property
    def latitude(self):
        if not self.birthplace:
            return False
        else:
            lat = City.objects.get(latitude=self)
            return lat.latitude

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        if not self.birthplace:
            return False
        else:
            lnt = City.objects.get(longitude=self)
            return lnt.longitude
```

My questions are:

1. How to get and autofill/pre-populate country's attribute at the Profile's class from city's attribute (which's a ForeignKey from City's class)? I've tried to get it by using @property decorator but I get *nothing* value.
2. Can I use same class (from City's class) for ForeignKey fields in one class (to Profile's class) together twice? In this case is city & birthplace attribute, and then repeat my question above for latitude & longitude's attribute from the birthplace's attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of populating these fields and @property calls? 
I would rather use direct call like this:

```
    person.city.country.name
    person.city.longitude
    person.city.latitude
```

It works with longitude and latitude properties as well. However if you need a pre-populated CharField you can do it in save() method like so:

```
    Class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.country = self.city.country.name
      self.longitude = self.city.country.name
      self.latitude = self.city.country.name
      super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And yes, you can use as many ForeignKey fields as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it help me but I end up by using this:
@property
def country(self):
    if not self.city:
        return False
    else:
        return self.city.country.name